# Book/Resource advise for OCA Java SE 7 1Z0-803/804 certifications

Tags: java

I am trying to attempt OCA JP certification soon. I have made some research online for resources to best prepare for the exam. Popular suggestions seem to be Java SE7 Essentials by Michael Ernest and Oracle Press Guides.

I was wondering if there were any other popular Video Tutorials/Books [particular to the cert exams] that the community might suggest. I am a student and a novice programmer so far. Pardon me if this question has been already asked a lot.

Thanks,
Matt

Edit 1: I realize there is an abundance of Java tutorials in general. My question is something that prepares me for the test and help me in general.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend the downloadable [application from Enthuware](http://www.enthuware.com/). The license is only 7 dollars, you have hundreds of questions, you will trained to not fall into all the trap questions of the Java exams (and there are a lot), you have a forum, entries linked by every question and at the result of every question, you get a very good explanation about the wrong questions and results, you can simulate the exams with several difficulty levels and so on.

I would not recommend a book except you are a total beginner. I made the OCA a 3/4 year ago and reading a book was waste of time (since I already knew Java). It would have been better for me to immediately start with Enthuware. If you just read a tutorial or book, you will probably not pass the exam.

By the way: At exam you only have 140min time. In Enthuware exams it's 150min, but this is wrong (it's even wrong at the Oracle site!)

Comment: Brilliant..!
Thanks for the heads up about timings :) ..!!

Answer (score -1):

Since you are a new programmer, so I would like to suggest you to collect OCA SE 7 Certificate Guide by Mala Gupta for OCA 1Z0-803 exam. I was helped by this book a lot, this is well covered the exam topics and simply explained.

Next, you can collect Java SE7 Associate Practice Exams  1Z0-803 by Hanumant Deshmukh for your mock practice, this book covered 5 standard test questions with answers explained as well as lots of chapter wise question and their explanation.

I also be recommend to download a license copy of Enthuware to have real exam mock practice.

The above mentioned two books are worth reading to save your time and not to get lost among tons of resources out there.

Comment: I am already using Hanumant Deshmukh.
In the place of other book i am using the Oracle press publication and I think it is pretty much the same.

I am really in love with Hanumanth Deshmukh though..
I think the tests are very good in the book although they are tough. They help prepare all aspects of the exam.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at Java Practice Questions by  Esteban Herrera. i am also in the middle of preparing for the exam and found his book quite valueable. the kindle download costs you only a few dollars for a book full of tricky questions.

you may also want to have a look at the path in the Oracle Tutorial regarding the Java certifications `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/certification/`

good luck for the exam.

btw: do you know whether the acutal passing score is to be printed on the issued certificate?

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the suggestions.

Regarding the results, you have the certificate that says you are a certified java programmer for the version you took and then there is a report that gives you the % which is your actual mark.

Check these:
Cert:
http://chmielua.cba.pl/cv/certs/images/fullscreen/oraclescjp.png

Report:
http://chmielua.cba.pl/cv/certs/images/fullscreen/scjp6.png

Comment: you're welcome. i can't open the files, though.

Comment: copy paste those links for example certificate and mark sheet..
They are some example i got off of google..

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to prepare as follows:

- Get [Enthuware](http://www.enthuware.com) and train mock exams
- Identify topics you are uncertain and read fundamentals in a book. I **highly** recommend '[OCA/COP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide](http://www.amazon.de/Programmer-Study-Guide-1Z0-803-1Z0-804/dp/0071772006)'.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Here are my sources for preparing to OCA Java 7 exam:

1. OCA OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide - 2015 Sierra K.Bates B - You can find it for free. The book is written by Exam creators. It's the best thing for preparing. But it requires some previous experience with Java. It's not for complete beginners. If you are new to Java, I'd suggest to start with something like "Head First Java" and then switch to this book
2. [Enthuware](http://enthuware.com/index.php/mock-exams/oracle-certified-associate/java-programmer-certification-i) - It's best simulator for Java exams and it costs just $10. It contains 7 Exams with 70 questions each, the same software as you'll see in actual exam and progress reports that I found very helpful during my study.    Now they released "Java SE 7 - I 1Z0-803" mock exams. So you have even more resources to train.
3. You can also make use of "OCP Java SE 6 Programmer Practise Exam" book for practicing purposes, which also contains 260+ exam questions and answers with explanations.
4. And last but not least, you should use flashcards for studying. It's proven    that flashcards are the best way to remember all the exam rules. They suggest it at their official guide. And I found it very useful

Good Luck with exam, and if you can't find any of books, you can contact me for this.